# Banner not shown

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, ads

I started to use advertising control, but I'm going crazy trying to let it work.
I copied *PivotPage.xaml* from [Microsoft Ad Control Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and made it the starting page in my app, but ad control is not shown (I'm not able to see banner); if I try to run Microsoft app, banner is shown.

So I registered my app on pubCenter and I got an appId and a unitId and tried to use them in my app, but the result is the same: no banner!!
If I try to use my ids in Microsoft app, test banner is shown.

Why using Microsoft example I'm able to see banner and using same page in my app I can't?
Why using my ids, Microsoft app does not show correct banner?

Here is XAML

```
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Grid.Row="0" Title="Ad Control Sample">

        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="piv 1">
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="piv 2">
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item three-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="piv 3">
        </controls:PivotItem>

    </controls:Pivot>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
        <TextBlock Text="This is the same ad." 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" />
        <my:AdControl Name="adControl1" 
                      ApplicationId="test_client" 
                      AdUnitId="Image480_80" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      Width="480" Height="80" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem and I want to share solution.
I add an event handler for `ErrorOccurred` on ad control and reading `Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e` I realized that my manifest (*WMAppManifest.xml*) was missing

```
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" />
<Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
```